# Почему не работает сдвиг по оси X в CSS?

Tags: html, css, transform

Не работает сдвиг по оси X, хотя в коде я написал, что он должен быть.

HTML:

```
<div id = "container">
  <div id = "logo" class = "d"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.d {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F44336;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}


@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
     transform: translateX(0px);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
     transform: translateX(500px);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
     transform: rotate(1240deg); 
  }
}

#logo {
  animation: rotate 2.5s ease-out 0s 1 normal;
}
```

```css
.d {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F44336;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(500px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1240deg);
  }
}

#logo {
  animation: rotate 2.5s ease-out 0s 1 normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo" class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Ссылка на код: https://jsfiddle.net/deloop_/qsr0gf35/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применяется только последнее свойство из

```
transform: translateX(500px);
transform: rotate(0deg);
```

В данном случае это `rotate`.

Чтобы применить несколько трансформаций их нужно разделить пробелом:

```
transform: translateX(500px) rotate(0deg);
```

```css
.d {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F44336;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1240deg);
  }
}

#logo {
  animation: rotate 2.5s ease-out 0s 1 normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo" class="d"></div>
</div>
```